# Rebel T6 EOS LCD Screen completely blank

Tags: canon

The LCD screen on my Rebel T6 is completely blank. I have tried all suggestions listed of similar questions to no avail. Battery is fully charged, I have taken battery out and replaced, clicked the on and off switch, Display button, Menu,ETC. Unfortunately, I did not purchase the extended warranty and my one warranty just expired. Any other suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Take it in for servicing.

Comment: Unfortunately, when a camera malfunctions and you've "tried everything"...the only thing left to do is send it in for repair. If the cost of that is more than the value of the camera or too high a percentage of its value to you, then get a new camera. Sorry mate, that's about all you can do.

Answer (score 1):

As you indicate `Any other suggestions welcomed` here are a few:

- Take the camera in for repairs. Don't expect it to be cheap.
- Use an external HDMI monitor to show the camera display on there.
- Tether the camera to a computer via USB and control it through EOS Utility.

For the last two suggestions you can search the [pdf manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300018254/02/eos-rebelt6i-750d-im2-en.pdf) and DuckDuckGo to find out how to do that.
If something is unclear, please [search Photo.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=search) before posting a new question.